# Simplificar operadores

Tags: c#, .net-core

Buen día.
Como podría simplificar la siguiente validación del IF:

```
if (!entrada.consulta.Contains("SELECT") && !entrada.consulta.Contains("INSERT") &&
                !entrada.consulta.Contains("UPDATE") && !entrada.consulta.Contains("DELETE") && !entrada.consulta.Contains("EXEC"))
            {
                log.EscribirLog($"Se detecto consulta erronea {entrada.consulta} con folio {respuestaError.Folio}");
                return BadRequest(respuestaError);
            }
```

Realmente no veo la manera, de antemano gracias.

ACTUALIZACIÓN:
He intentado lo siguiente, pero no realiza lo mismo ya que si la consulta no contiene alguna texto del listado, este no entra y no escribe el error en el Log.

```
List<string> list = new() {"SELECT","INSERT","DELETE","UPDATE","EXEC" };

            if (!list.Contains(entrada.consulta))
            {
                log.EscribirLog($"Se detecto consulta erronea {entrada.consulta} con folio {respuestaError.Folio}");
                return BadRequest(respuestaError);
            }
```

Comment: ¿Alguna respuesta te fue de utilidad?

Answer (score 0):

Te doy una idea no probada a partir de una constante

```
public enum Constante
    {
        select,
        insert,
        update,
        delete
    };
```

y luego aplicas

```
if(!entrada.consulta.Contains(Constante))
{
log.EscribirLog($"Se detecto consulta erronea {entrada.consulta} con folio {respuestaError.Folio}");
return BadRequest(respuestaError);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Aquí una alternativa, quizás es lo que buscas:

```
List<string> listaPalabrasValidas = new() {"SELECT","INSERT","DELETE","UPDATE","EXEC" };
var consulta = "select wasd from table qwerty;";

// Se crea un arreglo, e individualmente a cada palabra, la mandas a mayúscula.
var listaPalabrasEnConsulta = consulta.Split(' ').Select(x => x.ToUpper());

// Declaras una variable para leer con facilidad el IF Statement.    
var esValido = listaPalabrasEnConsulta.Any(palabra => listaPalabrasValidas.Contains(palabra)); 

// Preguntas si es valido y tomas acción:
if (esValido)
{
    Console.WriteLine($"Consulta acertada");                
} else {            
    Console.WriteLine($"Se detecto consulta erronea");                
}
```